# Delay in Consumer consuming messages in Apache Kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am using Kafka 0.8.0 and trying to achieve the below mentioned scenario.

**JCA API (Acts as a producer and sends data to)-----> Consumer------> HBase**

I am sending each message to consumer as soon as I fetch the data using JCA Client. For instance, as soon as producer sends message no.1 , I want to fetch the same from consumer and 'put' in HBase. But my consumer starts fetching the messages after some random n messages . I want to put the producer and consumer in sync so that both of them start working together.

I have used:

**1 broker**

**1 single topic**

**1 single producer and high level Consumer**

Can anyone suggest what do i need to do to achieve the same?

EDITED:

Adding some relevant code snippet.

**Consumer.java**

```
public class Consumer extends Thread {
    private final ConsumerConnector consumer;
    private final String topic;
    PrintWriter pw = null;
    int t = 0;
    StringDecoder kd = new StringDecoder(null);
    Map<String, Integer> topicCountMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    Map<String, List<KafkaStream<String, Signal>>> consumerMap;
    KafkaStream<String, Signal> stream;
    ConsumerIterator<String, Signal> it;

    public Consumer(String topic) {
        consumer = kafka.consumer.Consumer.createJavaConsumerConnector(createConsumerConfig());

        this.topic = topic;
        topicCountMap.put(topic, new Integer(1));
        consumerMap = consumer.createMessageStreams(topicCountMap, kd, new Serializer(
                new VerifiableProperties()));
        stream = consumerMap.get(topic).get(0);
        it = stream.iterator();

    }

    private static ConsumerConfig createConsumerConfig() {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("zookeeper.connect", KafkaProperties.zkConnect);
        props.put("group.id", KafkaProperties.groupId);
        props.put("zookeeper.session.timeout.ms", "400");
        props.put("zookeeper.sync.time.ms", "200");
        props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
        props.put("fetch.size", "1024");

        return new ConsumerConfig(props);

    }

    synchronized public void run() {

        while (it.hasNext()) {
            t = (it.next().message()).getChannelid();
            System.out.println("In Consumer received msg" + t);
        }
    }
}
```

**producer.java**

```
public class Producer {
    public final kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer<String, Signal> producer;
    private final String topic;
    private final Properties props = new Properties();

    public Producer(String topic)
    {
        props.put("serializer.class", "org.bigdata.kafka.Serializer");
        props.put("key.serializer.class", "kafka.serializer.StringEncoder");
        props.put("metadata.broker.list", "localhost:9092");
        // Use random partitioner. Don't need the key type. Just set it to Integer.
        // The message is of type userdefined Object .
        producer = new kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer<String,Signal(newProducerConfig(props));
        this.topic = topic;
    }
}
```

**KafkaProperties.java**

```
public interface KafkaProperties {
    final static String zkConnect = "127.0.0.1:2181";
    final static String groupId = "group1";
    final static String topic = "test00";
    final static String kafkaServerURL = "localhost";
    final static int kafkaServerPort = 9092;
    final static int kafkaProducerBufferSize = 64 * 1024;
    final static int connectionTimeOut = 100000;
    final static int reconnectInterval = 10000;
    final static String clientId = "SimpleConsumerDemoClient";
}
```

**This is how the consumer is behaving for the first 10 messages it does not sysout that message received by consumer but from the 11th message onwards it starts functioning correctly.**

```
     producer sending msg1

     producer sending msg2

     producer sending msg3

     producer sending msg4

     producer sending msg5

     producer sending msg6

     producer sending msg7

     producer sending msg8

     producer sending msg9

     producer sending msg10

     producer sending msg11

     producer sending msg12
     In Consumer received msg12

     producer sending msg13
     In Consumer received msg13

     producer sending msg14
     In Consumer received msg14

     producer sending msg15
     In Consumer received msg15

     producer sending msg16
     In Consumer received msg16

     producer sending msg17
     In Consumer received msg17

     producer sending msg18
     In Consumer received msg18

     producer sending msg19
     In Consumer received msg19

     producer sending msg20
     In Consumer received msg20

     producer sending msg21
     In Consumer received msg21
```

**EDITED: adding the listener function where producer is sending messages to consumer. And I am using the default producer config did not overwrite it**

```
public synchronized void onValueChanged(final MonitorEvent event_) {


    // Get the value from the DBR
    try {
        final DBR dbr = event_.getDBR();

        final String[] val = (String[]) dbr.getValue();

        producer1.producer.send(new KeyedMessage<String, Signal>         
                    (KafkaProperties.topic,new Signal(messageNo)));
        System.out.println("producer sending msg"+messageNo);

        messageNo++;


    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your producer and consumer code/configuration? Looks like some of them operate with batches (which is good thing, in fact).

Comment: @Dmitry added the code snippet.

Comment: Consumer seems to be ok (except property fetch.size = 1K - it means consumer cannot receive bigger messages, but probably it's not the problem we're looking for). Can you share code of newProducerConfig() and run() methods for producer?

Comment: @Dmitry My producer class is not threaded. I have one listener function which gets called whenever there is a change in a certain value and inside it i use the producer.send() function to send messages to the consumer.Anyways, I will share the listener function.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Try to add `props.put("request.required.acks", "1")` to producer configuration. By default producer doesn't wait for acks and message delivery is not guaranteed. So, if you start broker just before your test, producer may start to send messages before broker is fully initialized and first several messages may be lost.
2. Try to add `props.put("auto.offset.reset", "smallest")` to consumer configuration. It is equal to `--from-beginning` option of kafka-console-consumer.sh. If your consumer starts later than producer and there is no offset data saved in Zookeeper, then by default it will start consuming only new messages (see [Consumer configs](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#consumerconfigs) in docs).

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.Added the props.put("request.required.acks", "1") to producer but the program is behaving in a random manner. I ran the program 5 times each time with a new topic. But it gave different results all 5 times.Twice the producer and consumer were in sync rest of the times the consumer was delayed.

Comment: By 'delayed' you mean all messages were received, but not immediately after sending? In your original output first several messages were completely lost.

Comment: Yes,actually there are two scenarios :
1) Sometimes all messages were received, but not immediately after sending.
2) The other times several messages were lost as illustrated in the output provided.
But when i run this command "bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic topicname --from-beginning" from console,I get the same number of messages in consumer as produced by producer.
Why is that happening??

Comment: Added another suggestion to the answer.

Comment: Yea @Dmitry seems to be working. But using the property props.put("auto.offset.reset", "smallest"), would it mean that consumer would not keep a track of the offsets while fetching data from the same topic later after we produce some more data to it? Won't we be getting duplicate data that we have already read from the consumer?

Comment: No, this option is only used when there is no initial offset in Zookeeper.

Comment: I produced more data to the same topic and tried to see how the consumer was behaving. My Observations:

1. When i started afresh with a new topic there was no data loss.

2. Produced more data to the same topic and saw that the consumer was fetching some random(5 or 6) messages which it had already read in the 1st run. So there is slight duplication when consumer is reading data from the same topic. 
So, IMO there seems to be a problem with the offset. Can it be rectified?

Comment: Try to call consumer.shutdown() before exit. It will sync consumed offsets.

Comment: Hi @Dmitry , I got my problem resolved following this replies. I also have one query. Is it possible to have fixed size (say 5) thread pool to handle messages from any number (say 100 or more) of topics?

Comment: For the latests kafka release 12.1 0.10.1.0 the configs should be changed to : Producer: ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG,"1"     Consumer : ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest"

Answer (score 0):

One of possibility is Kafka Lag. May be the consumer is overloaded with too many partitions. Or processing per message is very costly.