# Why consumer can't see the messages right after topic is created (programatically) and messages are published?

Tags: apache-kafka

I am observing that if I create the topic and publish the messages right after the topic is created (all within same producer program), the consumer program doesn't get partitions assigned (ie., the `consumer.assignment()` returns empty partitions list). However, if I add some wait before the consumer subscribes to the topic then the partition assignment works fine and consumer receives the messages.

Why is that?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21727150/delay-in-consumer-consuming-messages-in-apache-kafka

Answer (score 0):

Sending message is asynchronous, meaning send method only adds records to a buffer and returns immediately. If you starts reading right after calling the send. The to-be-transmitted records might still be in the buffer space. That's why you have to wait some time to see the produced messages. For your scenario, KafkaProducer offers a **flush** method which makes all buffered records immediately available to send (even if linger.ms is greater than 0) and blocks on the completion of the requests associated with these records. See code below:

```
for(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record: consumer.poll(100))
    producer.send(new ProducerRecord("my-topic", record.key(), record.value());
producer.flush();
consumer.commit();
```

Comment: Thanks but it still doesn't explain why partition assignment fails. I can understand that messages will not be seen immediately but shouldn't 1 or more partitions be assigned to consumer if the topic creation went successfully even if consumer subscribed to the topic immediately after it was created?

Comment: This means either the assignment hasn't happened yet, or the partitions are in the process of getting reassigned if topic subscription was used.

Comment: so the only solution to deal with such situation is to just introduce the wait or is there another way to ensure that kafka brokers are ready for partition assignments before calling `consumer.subscribe()`?

Comment: Invoke KafkaConsumer.assignment() to check if the assignment hasn't happened yet, or the partitions are in the process of getting reassigned. Return none for these cases.